# Can I use same integration run time server for multiple on-premise environments

Tags: sftp, azure-data-factory

We have IR server installed for ADF to connect on-premise environment.
Now we have another requirement, that we need to connect to one of the on-premise SFTP server and pull the files from their network.

Can I use the existed IR server to connect to SFTP of other on-premise environment.

Here two on-premise networks are different.

Regards,
Srinivas

Comment: Hi SRINIVAS REDDY Badikela, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can  mark it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same IR for as many data sources as you want, as long it can reach them. If the vm where the IR is installed can reach the other environment, then of course you can! 
If not, maybe you can talk with a network admin to figure out some way.

If none of this is possible, then just install a new IR on a vm in this new environment.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

You can associate a self-hosted integration runtime with multiple on-premises machines or virtual machines in Azure. These machines are called nodes. You can have up to four nodes associated with a self-hosted integration runtime.

You can associate multiple nodes by installing the self-hosted integration runtime software from Download Center. Then, register it by using either of the authentication keys that were obtained from the **New-AzDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntimeKey** cmdlet, as described in the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-hybrid-copy-powershell).

Note

You don't need to create a new self-hosted integration runtime to associate each node. You can install the self-hosted integration runtime on another machine and register it by using the same authentication key.

For more details, please reference: [High availability and scalability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime#high-availability-and-scalability)